# I have to scrape a div and it has 2 tags inside it <img> and <sup> i need to content of sup tag but I have to remove the content of img tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Sample html code:

```
<div>
Hello everyone how are you
<sup>Hello hi</sup>
<figure>Blah Blah<img /><figure>
</div>
```

I tried using decompose() function in BeautifulSoup but it also destroys the sup tag. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

To get text of the `<sup>` tag:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<div>
Hello everyone how are you
<sup>Hello hi</sup>
<figure>Blah Blah<img /></figure>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.sup.text)
```

Prints:

```
Hello hi
```

---

To remove the `<img />` tag:

```py
soup.img.extract()
print(soup.div)
```

Prints:

```html
<div>
Hello everyone how are you
<sup>Hello hi</sup>
<figure>Blah Blah</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """\
<div>
Hello everyone how are you
<sup>Hello hi</sup>
<figure>Blah Blah<img /></figure>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'lxml')
a = soup.find('div')
b = a.find('sup').text

print(b)
```

Sorry if something isnt right but i am on the phone and i cant test it out. And  you need to do `pip install lxml` and at the `file.html` put the file or the website